# htaccess rewrite rule all existing files and directories in one domain go to same filepath in another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to write an htaccess rewrite rule to send all existing files and directories at the domain http:// or https:// and www or not lun.re to lunre.com.

So lun.re/admin, which does exist would go to lunre.com, but lun.re/new, which doesn't exist would stay at lun.re, but would redirect to https://lun.re/new.

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lun\.re$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lun\.re$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://lunre.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Lines 5-8 were already there from my hosting provider.

I've also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /loader.php [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?lun.re$
RewriteRule ^ http://lunre.com/ [L,R]
```

But then I get a too many redirects error.

What exactly I am trying to do is if it does exist and the domain is lun.re then go to https://lunre.com/file-or-dir (the same filepath at the long url) otherwise if it doesn't exist then stay at the current domain and go to https://currentdomain/loader.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect all existing files/directories to http://lunre.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?lun.re$
RewriteRule ^ http://lunre.com/ [L,R]
```

You don't need a RewriteRule to Redirect non-existent requests back to your main domain as the Rule only redirects existing files/folders.

Comment: This seems to be redirecting files and dirs that don't exist to lunre.com too. I'm getting a 302 found when I go to lun.re/new, but the directory /new does NOT exist? Even when I try something random that I also know doesn't exist, like lun.re/ddsfs it goes to lunre.com. I only want existing files and dirs to do that redriect and non existing to go to /loader.php, which I thought I was doing with the next line: `ErrorDocument 404 /loader.php`

Comment: I updated my question with what exactly I am trying to do along with something else that I tried.

Comment: I tried it in an incognito window and in a browser I have never tried it in before so there can’t be cache now. Still it is saying directories that don’t exist, they are redirecting to lunre.com. Is there a way I can do if doesn’t exist send to /loader.php, else if the domain is lun.re, send to same filepath in lunre.com else redirect to https? Thank you for the help!